# CSS Repeat background before element - to edge of browser

Tags: css

I'd like the background colour of a h tag to repeat to the edge of the browser window from behind the element itself - ie from left hand side right up to the element itself..

I started messing round with :before - but cant think of a method to achieve this style - can anyone offer any assistance..

```
.tit-rep:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qd0kn19k/

Comment: you need the element to cover the whole width of screen. You might get around by setting the position:absolute on the before element

Comment: just try to define `display: block;` instead of `inline-block` for `.tit-rep`.  https://jsfiddle.net/ap5dxzhh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `.tit-tep` to `position:relative` and the `:before` to `position:absolute`.

Then you need to stretch the `:before` and the easiest way is to use the `vw` unit.

```
.tit-rep{position:relative} /*add it to your existing rule*/
.tit-rep:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100%; /*make it extend to the left*/
  width:50vw; /*50% of browser width*/
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/qd0kn19k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this to get you in the right direction.

```
.tit-rep:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  height:30px;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all background details from the element to the `:before` pseudo-element

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd0kn19k/3/)